# Equivalent definitions of the Schwarz space

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, definition, schwartz-space

In different places I've seen Schwarz functions defined by
$$\sup_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left(1+|x|\right)^N|D^\alpha \psi(x)| < \infty$$
and by
$$\sup_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left(1+|x|^2\right)^N|D^\alpha \psi(x)| < \infty.$$

I wish to show these are equivalent conditions. That the latter implies the first is easy: both expressions are bounded in the unit ball, so we only need to check how they behave outside of it, and
$$(1+|x|)\le (1+|x|^2)$$
outside the unit ball.

How could one show the other direction?

Comment: Take $2N$ in the first condition and $N$ in the second. Then for large $|x|$, both behave like $|x|^{2N}$, meaning their quotient tends to $1$, so you can bound the second by a constant multiple of the first.

Comment: Sometimes people also use $N/2$ as exponent in the second case which is then even more a smooth version of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It follows by taking $2N$ in the first criterion and the fact that
$$
(1+|x|)^{2N} = (1 + 2\,|x|+|x|^2)^N \geq (1+|x|^2)^N. 
$$